# I need to mock the @Bean but somehow the actual bean is being created during the junit execution

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a requiremenmt where I need to mock a particular Spring bean, but during the JUnit execution the actual bean is being is also instantiated.

For example:

```
@Configuration
public class Config{

  @Bean
  public Foo fooBean(){
    return new Foo();
  }
}
```

Here is my code to Mock the `Foo` spring bean, so that during the JUnit execution, only the mocked `Foo` bean be created.

```
@Configuration
public class MockFooBean{

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public Foo mockedBean(){
    Mockito.mock(Foo.class)
  }
}
```

The requirement is during the JUnit execution I want to have ***mockedBean()*** to be called (Which is happening right now), BUT I do not want ***fooBean()*** to be called again, for the `Foo` bean creation.

**Edited Recently:**

Still no luck. I tried below:

```
@Configuration
public class MockFooBean{

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public Foo mockedBean(){
    Mockito.mock(Foo.class)
  }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=MockFooBean.class, loader=AnnotationConfigurationContextLoader.class)
public class TestClass{

@Autowired
private ClassUnderTest classUnderTest;

//JUNITS//

}
```

I terribly miss the good old days where we have good control over the code. Any help?

Comment: You would have to show what runner you are using for your test. Also are you pointing to your test configuration so that Spring can pick it up for tests? Also have a look at `@MockBean`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should have separate configuration for tests. separate beans for tests so they will not be loaded while running tests.

you can go through below link

https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles

Answer (score 0):

Because `@TestConfiguration` is an addition to the current configuration(s). It is not executed instead of the current configuration(s) but it adds and replaces (if already defined) beans that it specifies.
So the current configuration(s) is first loaded and the `TestConfiguration` is then loaded.
[From the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-detecting-config) :

> If you want to customize the primary configuration, you can use a
>   nested @TestConfiguration class. Unlike a nested @Configuration class,
>   which would be used instead of your application’s primary
>   configuration, a nested @TestConfiguration class is used in addition
>   to your application’s primary configuration.

To not allow Spring to instantiate the bean that you override, you have to exclude it from the context. To achieve that you could use :

- specific configuration for tests
- profiles
- `@ConditionalOnProperty` .

For example with a specific configuration for tests :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest // or a slicing test
@Import(MyTestsConfiguration.class)
public class FooTest {
   //...    
}
```

For example with profiles :

```
@Profile("prod")
@Configuration
public class Config{

  @Bean
  public Foo fooBean(){
    return new Foo();
  }
}

@Profile("test")
@Configuration
public class MockFooBean{

  @Bean
  @Primary
  public Foo mockedBean(){
    Mockito.mock(Foo.class)
  }
}
```

And in the test, active the `test` profile :

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest // or a slicing test
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class FooTest{
  ....
}
```